# Can't update SQL Server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

everyone.

I am relatively new to Java (a complete noob), but have had experience with VB.Net.

I am trying to update a row in a SQL2008 table.

The table name is _Registry.

When I compile the code below, it fails with several errors (listed separately after the code). If I comment out the section from where it says "**// And here is where I run into issues**" to the catch block, it runs fine (except the table wasn't updated).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String host = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER1\\Primrose;databaseName=Primrose";
    String uName = "sa";
    String uPwd = "P@ssw0rd";

// The two SQL statements I am using:

    String queryDB = "SELECT * FROM _Registry WHERE Section = 'RecIds' AND Key_ = '_Folders' AND User_ = 'sc_general'";
    String updateDB = "UPDATE _Registry SET Value WHERE RecID = 5";

// These are the 6 columns in the table named _Registry:
    int getRecId;           // RecId  [int]  IDENTITY(1,4)  
    String getUser;         // User_  [char](64)
    String getSection;      // Section [char](64)
    String getKey;          // Key_  [char](64)
    String getValue;        // Value  [char](255)
    String getExtraInfo;    // ExtraInfo  [text]

    int totalFolders = 10;  // This is a static test value that will be used to ensure I can update the table:

// Everything works from here until I exit the WHILE loop:
    try
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPwd);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryDB);

        // Keep reading through the table until I get my desired result:
        while (rs.next())
        {
            getRecId = rs.getInt("RecId");
            getUser = rs.getString("User_");
            getSection = rs.getString("Section");
            getKey = rs.getString("Key_");
            getValue = rs.getString("Value");
            getExtraInfo = rs.getString("ExtraInfo");

            getValue = getValue.trim();    // Strip trailing spaces from string

            int newValue = Integer.parseInt(getValue) + 1;    // Convert string to number so I can add it to total folders in template
            newValue = newValue + totalFolders;    // Change to total + existing value to write back to dB
        getValue = Integer.toString(newValue);
        }

// And here is where I run into issues - I even tried
// this "rs = stmt.executeUpdate(updateDB)" but that had no effect:

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(updateDB);

        rs.updateInt( "RecId", getRecId );
        rs.updateString( "User_", getUser );
        rs.updateString( "Section", getSection );
        rs.updateString( "Key_", getKey );
        rs.updateString( "Value", getValue );
        rs.updateString( "ExtraInfo", getExtraInfo );
        rs.updateRow();

        System.out.println("Updated successfully!");
    }

    catch ( SQLException err )  
    {  
        System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
    }  
}
```

And here is the compiler output:

```
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Java\DBupdate\build\classes

C:\Java\DBupdate\src\dbupdate\DBupdate.java:73: error: variable getRecId might not have been initialized
            rs.updateInt( "RecId", getRecId );
                                   ^

C:\Java\DBupdate\src\dbupdate\DBupdate.java:74: error: variable getUser might not have been initialized
            rs.updateString( "User_", getUser );
                                      ^

C:\Java\DBupdate\src\dbupdate\DBupdate.java:75: error: variable getSection might not have been initialized
            rs.updateString( "Section", getSection );
                                        ^

C:\Java\DBupdate\src\dbupdate\DBupdate.java:76: error: variable getKey might not have been initialized
            rs.updateString( "Key_", getKey );
                                     ^

C:\Java\DBupdate\src\dbupdate\DBupdate.java:77: error: variable getValue might not have been initialized
            rs.updateString( "Value", getValue );
                                      ^

C:\Java\DBupdate\src\dbupdate\DBupdate.java:78: error: variable getExtraInfo might not have been initialized
            rs.updateString( "ExtraInfo", getExtraInfo );
                                          ^
6 errors

C:\Java\DBupdate\nbproject\build-impl.xml:926: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Java\DBupdate\nbproject\build-impl.xml:268: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: What do you expect the value of `getRecId` to be if the query doesn't return any results?

Answer (score 3):

As the errors indicate, you're trying to use variables that may not have been initialized. Try initializing them to null, or ensuring that you set them to some useful value before you try to read from them.

Also, your SQL update query is invalid: you can't just `SET Value`, you have to `SET Value=` and give it some value.

Comment: You guys were all awesome - I applied your suggestions and it worked!

However, while it seems to work (the table is now updated with the expected results, when I run the program in NetBeans, I see this output - all I want to see is the success message if it worked - is this just a NetBeans thing?

`code`run:
`code`5
`code`sc_general
`code`RecIds
`code`_FOLDERS
`code`1023
`code`null

`code`String after changing getValue: 
`code`5
`code`sc_general
`code`RecIds
`code`_FOLDERS
`code`1034
`code`null

`code`The statement did not return a result set.
`code`BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: It's due to all of the `System.out.println` calls - those output to console, which, if you run from within NetBeans, is the NetBeans console panel.

Comment: Actually, the message is generated by the CATCH block - as soon as the "rs = stmt.executeQuery(updateDB);" is executed. I can't understand why...

Answer (score 1):

A 'Variable might not have been initialized' error means just what it says. Since the declaration of these variables is inside the while loop, what would happen if no results were returned from the database? Answer: the variables would not be initialized because the body of the while loop never executed. Try declaring these variables to a default value outside the loop and code should compile.